# what are quaternions and how can I use them?

Tags: ros, bullet, quaternion, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen quaternions in tf and bullet but I don't know what they are or how to use them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9981/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them?/) by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-17

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quaternions are a representation of orientation [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

For advanced concepts there's an extensive reference written by [Erik Dam](http://www.itu.dk/people/erikdam/DOWNLOAD/98-5.pdf)

There's a good [primer](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Quaternion+and+Rotation+Primer) on the ogre website.

O.Khatib lectures (from Stanford) on introduction to robotics are freely available from the iTunes U store and can be accessed [here](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS223A). There is a part elaborating on rotation representations.

There's also a great tutorial at https://eater.net/quaternions

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 23

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on 2013-03-03**:
I encourage to learn the mathematical concept before going on. Wikipedia may serve for this purpose, as KoenBuys said.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to complement the idea. A **dual** quaternion can be used to define a rigid body **rotation AND translation** of an angle θ about an axis u through the origin. I realy don't known which kind of quaternion is implemented in TF, maybe just the rotational.

[Here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/other/dualQuaternion/index.htm) you can found an interresting web site about quaternions. And [here](http://www.ingegneriameccanica.org/papers/pennestrivalentini_paper.pdf) a very good paper with a tutorial and a real application.

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-17**:
A ROS pose is the position as xyz and a quaternion for rotation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started a [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions). Hopefully others will add to it.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8